# Is there a way in Gatsby to export inlined styled components CSS into a CSS file?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components, server-side-rendering, css-in-js

I have accomplished my first Gatsby app, which will be going to production soon. Here's the link: https://majiid-landing-page.vercel.app/

I have used styled components throughout the app, I usually take the `SCSS` with `BEM` approach, but I wanted to try this `CSS in JS` approach.

The issue is that the page first appears unstyled for a fraction of a second, then the styles are parsed, like if those were injected with `JS`, while the styles are actually in the HTML as Gatsby uses `SSR`.

Is this the normal behaviour?

I'm not sure how to reproduce the whole thing as the repo is private anyways I'm using `GlobalStyles` as well as specific styles in every component.

Here's some snippets:

Global Styles

```
import React from "react";

import Abstracts from "./abstracts/abstracts";
import Base from "./base/base";
import Utils from "./utils/utils";

const GlobalStyles = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Abstracts />
      <Base />
      <Utils />
    </>
  );
};

export default GlobalStyles;
```

Example of global styles creation:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

export default createGlobalStyle`
  :root {
      // COLORS
    --body-background: #ffffff;
  }
`;
```

Gatsby SSR

```
// gatsby-ssr.js
const React = require("react");
require("./src/scss/index.scss");
const GlobalStyles = require("./src/styles/global-styles").default;
const Layout = require("./src/layout/Layout").default;

exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Layout>{element}</Layout>
    </>
  );
};
```

gatsby-browser.js

```
const React = require("react");
require("./src/scss/index.scss");
const GlobalStyles = require("./src/styles/global-styles").default;
const Layout = require("./src/layout/Layout").default;

exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  console.log("Running this");
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Layout>{element}</Layout>
    </>
  );
};
```

Gatsby Config (extract):

```
plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components",
...
```

package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@vimeo/player": "^2.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.13.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "gatsby": "^3.11.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^4.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^4.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-webfonts": "^2.1.1",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^5.11.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.11.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.11.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "polished": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has made it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_dVwrhvkBI

Basically the Global Styles have to be applied in a wrapPageElement hook instead of the wrapRootElement one.

I'll leave it here if anyone else searches SO to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's called FOUC (**F**lash **O**f **U**nstyled **C**ontent) and no, it's not the "normal" behavior but it's quite common using styled-components.

Without further details, it's impossible to guess what can possibly go wrong or is misconfigured but it's usually fixed by:

- Installing all the required [plugins](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-styled-components/):

  ```
  npm install gatsby-plugin-styled-components styled-components babel-plugin-styled-components
  ```
- Adding the proper configuration in your `gatsby-config.js`:

  ```
  {
     resolve: `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
     options: {
        // Add any options here
     },
  },
  ```
- Wrapping your `GlobalStyles` in your `Layout` component. Something like:

  ```
  import React from "react"
  import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"

  const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
     body {
       color: ${props => (props.theme === "purple" ? "purple" : "white")};
     }
  `
  export default function Layout({ children }) {
     return (
       <>
         <GlobalStyle theme="purple" />
         {children}
       </>
     )
  }
  ```

  Other implementation details at https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/styled-components/
- Alternatively to the last point, you can use `wrapPageElement` API in your `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js` (both files, this is important).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've updated the question for improved clarity!

Comment: Try the 3rd case (the layout) to see if you gain any performance. Also, check https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20594#issuecomment-675106531

Comment: Thanks! I tried moving the global styles declaration in the Layout component but it didn't help.. I tried serving the static files locally and it has the same issue so I don't think Netlify is the issue (as the guy in the issue referenced). Do you think I should use some webpack plugin to extract the inline css in a separate file?

Comment: No, this should be managed by the plugin itself. The GitHub thread suggests wrapping it in a theme. In other cases is because of plugin duplicity... double-check everything to be sure, it's 90% of cases a misconfiguration somewhere.

Comment: I found a solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_dVwrhvkBI